# Replace item4 and item5 with item3

Tags: text-processing, awk

If I have a data like this,

```
1 item1,
2 item2,
3 item3,
4 item4,
5 item5
```

I want to replace item4 and item5 with item3

Is there any other than this?

```
awk -F ' ' '{gsub("item4","item3",$2);gsub("item5","item3",$2); print}' OFS=" " file
```

Comment: Is this one line from the file?

Answer (score 1):

It's `<input sed -r 's/item[45]/item3/' >output`

You will have

```
1 item1,
2 item2,
3 item3,
4 item3,
5 item3
```

If you have also `item48`, `item522`, etc.

it's

```
<input sed -E 's/^([0-9]{1,} +)item[45](,?)$/\1item3\3/' >output
```

Comment: Just taken item numbers as example

actual was like

1 VA
2 GA
3 NV
4 NZ
5 IN

I want to replace IN and NZ with NV, GA with CV and VA with CO

Comment: @BhargavMandava then please edit your question and give us data that represent what you actually have! Otherwise we will waste your time (and ours) with solutions that won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To not match lines with `item44` or `item51`, test for an optional comma (`,?`) and the end of the field (`$`) before you replace the values (like in [aborruso's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567609/332764) `sed` solution):

```
awk '$2 ~ /^item[45],?$/{ gsub(/item[45]/, "item3", $2) } 1' file
```

Or with GNU `awk`'s `gensub`:

```
awk '{ $2=gensub(/^item[45](,?)$/, "item3\\1", 1, $2) } 1' file
```

Comment: Just taken item numbers as example

actual was like

1 VA
2 GA
3 NV
4 NZ
5 IN

I want to replace IN and NZ with NV, GA with CV and VA with CO

Comment: These are different requirements and your method wouldn't be that bad: `awk '{gsub(/IN|NZ/,"NV",$2); gsub("GA","CV",$2); gsub("VA","CO",$2)} 1' file`